# harware implemenation of multiplier

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hardware

i am trying to write a verilog code for harware implemenation of multiplier...but i am getting certain error
my code is

here i take 4 bit input and 4 bit output....and then muliply first bit of multiplier with multiplicand...and store result in p...similarly second bit of multiplier with multiplicand and store in q...which further i took one 5 bit register and sote value in it....ansd so on for rest code

```
    module multiplier(a,b,c
        );

    input [3:0]a;
    input [3:0]b;
    output [7:0]c;

    wire [3:0]p;
    wire [3:0]q;
    wire [3:0]r;
    wire [3:0]s;
    wire [4:0]t;
     wire [5:0]u;
     wire [6:0]v;
     assign [3:0]p = {4{b[0]}} & [3:0]a ;   ////////ERROR///////
    assign [3:0]q = {4{b[1]}} & [3:0]a ;


    assign [3:0]r = {4{b[2]}} & [3:0]a ;
    assign [3:0]s = {4{b[3]}} & [3:0]a ;

    assign [4:1]t = [3:0]q;
    assign [5:2]u = [3:0]r;
    assign [6:3]v = [3:0]s;
    endmodule

    ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "multiplier.v" line 34 unexpected token: '['
    ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "multiplier.v" line 34 unexpected token: '['
    ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "multiplier.v" line 34 expecting ';', found ':'
    ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "multiplier.v" line 34 expecting 'endmodule', found '0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Brackets (`[]`) on the left of a signal name is only used with defining a packed array. After that the brackets are used to the right of the signals.

Example, your:

```
assign [3:0]p = {4{b[0]}} & [3:0]a ;
```

should be:

```
assign p[3:0] = {4{b[0]}} & a[3:0] ;
```

or use the full range:

```
assign p = {4{b[0]}} & a ;
```